# Switching the motherboard of my Compaq laptop

Tags: laptop, motherboard

[Tech specs:](http://www.walmart.com/catalog/DescribeBundleComponent.do?bundle_id=10966053&component_id=1&item_id=14575751)

- Intel Celeron 900 processor
  2.2GHz, 800MHz Front Side Bus, 1MB Cache
- 2GB DDR2 system memory
- 250GB SATA hard drive

  ---

I have a Compaq Presario CQ62, as seen in the link above. I don't like it. It isn't fast enough, it's not a gaming computer, and it freezes when I'm programming and developing (I didn't buy it for myself).

Now, I would like to switch the motherboard of my computer. I would just switch out the processor, and put new memory into it, but I don't think it'll fit correctly (if it will please tell me).

If I put a new motherboard in, will anything on my hard drive be cleared if I don't touch it? I know I will have to reinstall my OS (right?), but will that affect any files?

*Note: I will not be doing this. I am hiring a pro. So don't be worried if I sound like I don't know what I'm saying :P.*

Comment: Not usually a simple process as laptop MB are unique to the device.  Getting another laptop will be easier.

Comment: *> I would just switch out the processor, and put new memory into it, but I don't think it'll fit correctly*   New RAM should be fine; a compatible SODIMM would work. A new CPU may or may not fit the motherboard; it depends on what the existing socket is (the laptop specs are vague about that) and what the new CPU is.

Comment: My CQ62 (EU version) had the freezing-issue. I received a new HDD which fixed the freezing. But it's *definitely not* made for gaming though.

Comment: Then you have to change the motherboard its not the processor which let you play the game its graphic card which is fit in the motherboard for the laptop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have to check out that which motherboard can support your laptop. You should consider with the HP that you want to upgrade the motherboard and which one can fit to your requirements otherwise its not guaranty  that the motherboard will fit with your system.  If you want to just change the RAM then its OK but if you want to change the processor then it could be fit or not as their socket may differ.

Nothing will erase form the hard disk. If your new motherboards chipset is the same as old one then no need of reinstall the OS but some times you have to repair the OS not a clean install but I will recommend you to take a backup of your important data before upgrade.

Follow this guide for the repair [windows-7](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/toolsofthetrade/ss/windows-7-startup-repair.htm) as you have not told which OS you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Since the title says "**Switching the motherboard** of my Compaq laptop": most likely it will not fit correctly (laptop motherboards are designed for specific models). **Maybe** (and that's a big maybe) if you find a motherboard for a similar model you can fit it.

Really, it's easier to just get a new laptop.

But even if you could swap motherboards, the laptop hard drive wouldn't be erased; however, you might need to reinstall the OS if the motherboards are sufficiently different.

Comment: *> Most likely it will not fit correctly (laptop motherboards are designed for specific models).*   They were asking about a new CPU and RAM fitting the motherboard, not the board fitting the chassis. The part about the hard-drive was useful though.